# Crosswords Puzzle Database or Web Service

Tags: database, web-services, dump, crossword

I would like to obtain an existing db dump of a collection of crossword puzzles or a web service through which I can get one. Is any one aware of any web sites that provide you with free dumps?

Thanks in advance

John

Comment: possible duplicate: [Crossword web services or Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498191/crossword-web-services-or-database)

Answer (score 0):

You need to design a bot for this. You can use open source toold like snoopy, or more easy approach is to use FF plugins. If you need have a very complex algo in mind to get data , use Kapaoo.